# Swift vs Objective-C - for reusing C++ code

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, swift

We have an android application having the critical code written in C++ in JNI library.

We are about to implement iOS version of the same application. The plan is to implement in Objective-c as it's straight forward to integrate C code with it. However, as Swift is picking up, we would like to have suggestion on Swift vs Objective-C keeping in mind that we have to use the existing C++ libraries and any Swift bottlenecks.

Comment: Objective-C is definitely still easier to use with C++ than Swift is.

Answer (score 1):

The way to reuse C++ code is to write an Objective-C wrapper class, with the header file containing nothing that is C++, but the implementation file written in Objective-C++ (.mm suffix).

An Objective-C class can be used from Swift and from Objective-C, so for a Swift project, it doesn't matter if you have a few Objective-C classes.

There is no way currently to call C++ from Swift directly, and I wouldn't expect it for a while. And if you look at how you call C from Swift, you'll probably decide that you are quite happy with the situation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem writing a Swift application and integrate in it a c++ source code.

Here are the steps:

1) Add the c++ source files to your Xcode project. If you are using a 3rd party libreries you will need to add it as framework to your project.

2) create a Header bridge file and add it to you project. This file will have the c++ functions signature you will like to use from the swift modules. as explained in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

3) When you call the c++ functions mention in the Header Bridge file you need to create a special pointers object, as described in - 
https://gist.github.com/neilpa/b430d148d1c5f4ae5ddd

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responding. After careful consideration, we decided to go with Objective-C and even released the application.

One of the key reason was that most developers in our company are proficient in C/C++ and Objective-c was easy to get comfortable with than the Swift.

Integration with existing C/C++ code was easy without any bridging code once we defined the Makefile templates and used them within existing Makefiles. Only additional thing was to make scripts for fat libraries.

Hence based on our experience, I will recommend Objective-C over Swift.